# Transferring Magento website, admin panel URL gives 404

Tags: admin, login, 404-page, migration

I'm having a problem which I've never experienced before when moving a Magento website to a new server.

The transfer was complete and the website is working fine, the only problem is that the admin URL gives a 404 page.

The URL for the admin panel was suppose to be:

http://mysite.com/admin

I've also tried:

http://mysite.com/index.php/admin

However the 404 is still there.

I've had a look at the local.xml and the  tag is set to 'admin'.

var session/cache was all deleted. The rest of the site seems to work fine apart from this 404 error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

404 issues are quite common when migrating Magento installations between servers. As per this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) please see the following answer

[Magento Admin 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871501/magento-admin-404)

You need to go your server directly and do this via SSH/ FTP

You have to delete the following file:

```
app/etc/use_cache.ser
```

If you get an error after that like:

> Notice: Undefined index: 0 in /srv/www/vhosts/javra.com/htdocs/munchad2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Config.php on line 92

Then go to your Database Management:

- Open PhpMyAdmin
- Go to your database
- Click SQL
- Run the following SQL Query

_

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Definitely backup the file & your database prior to running these changes.

Alternately, double check your .htaccess files which are also sometimes the bane of the issue.

Comment: My 'app/etc/use_cache.ser' didn't exist so I just ran the SQL queries, they worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Interesting, strange how something like that vanishes during a migration. Glad you managed to sort things out.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, yet running the SQL query doesn't change anything. Those values are already okay.

Comment: My Magento database doesn't even have these tables so I can't run it..?

Comment: `app/etc/use_cache.ser` is a holdover from Magento 1.3.x.x and isn't used by 1.4.x.x and later. The cache information held in this file was moved into a database table.

Comment: My 'app/etc/use_cache.ser' didn't exist so I just ran the SQL queries, but it's not working

Comment: I didn't find 'app/etc/use_cache.s‌​er & just run command return is "# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)." & admin still 404

Answer (score -2):

It might be, that you didn't export the AUTOINCREMENT keys, this leads to the problem, that all the stuff which in Magento has normally id 0, like:

- admin store
- NOT_LOGGED_IN customer group

has some id which leads to problems.

To fix the store, you have to run:

```
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code = 'admin';
```

**But be careful, because there might be more broken!**