# Error 404 - Can't access backend after moving to new server

Tags: admin, magento-1, 404-page, server-setup, 404

I have moved my website on a new server (domain name is the same). Frontend is working properly but the admin login page gives a `404 Not Found` error.

Most posts about this issue suggest the solutions mentioned on this post [Transferring Magento website, admin panel URL gives 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/transferring-magento-website-admin-panel-url-gives-404)

I've tried all of them but nothing worked. Is there something else I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

The reason for this error is that store_id and website_id for admin should be set to 0 (zero). But, when you import database to new server, somehow these values are not set to 0.

Open PhpMyAdmin and run the following query in your database:-

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Back up database before making any changes also see log file to find exact issue.
Also you can refer link [404 magento admin error](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-solution-to-error-404-not-found-in-admin-login-page/)
Hope this is helpful to you

Comment: Hi, I have already done that, but didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for that ...

Comment: The link suggests the same solution that you mentioned and I also cleared cache. Still not fixed though

Answer (score 4):

I've run into a couple of things myself that could cause this

- make sure the .htaccess is in place in the root directory
- make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled on the new server
- check the Base urls in the `core_config_data` table
- make sure caching is off or refreshed
- check file owner and permissions of the files

Answer (score 2):

You need to go your server directly and do this via SSH/ FTP

You have to delete the following file

```
 app/etc/use_cache.ser
```

If you get an error after that like

```
 Notice: Undefined index: 0 in /srv/www/vhosts/javra.com/htdocs/munchad2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Config.php on line 92
```

Then go to your Database Management.

Open PhpMyAdmin
Go to your database
Click SQL
Run the following SQL Query:
_

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE     customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Some thing strange happens with the cache when you move the databases from one server to another so it seems like you need to clear it out.

Comment: hi check This solution?

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS..re import ur db
backup your database add the line below to the top of the .sql file. This will prevent SQL from automatically assigning the id of 1 when we need it to be 0.

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */
```

if no success check this link also after tried the above mentioned one
[Magento 404 on Admin Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/magento-404-on-admin-page)

Answer (score 2):

Open `PhpMyAdmin` and run the following query in your database

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

then remove two folders from `file manager->var -> cache`  &  `session`

Comment: As opposed to other suggestions, this was the correct process I needed to run. The query works to gain access but I still had to clear the other 2 folders.

Answer (score 1):

just add these in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## Enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## You can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## Workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## Rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

We've moved servers a few times and each time we had the same or similar issues. We've made a catch all script we run on each new server and it's worked to fix all our issues for the last two migrations, you can give it a shot! The problem has usually been around the old url being stuck or cached somewhere or a permission is out of whack..

```
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/full_page_cache/
rm -rf media/catalog/product/cache
rm -rf var/session/*
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
chown -R apache .
systemctl restart mysqld
systemctl restart httpd 

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find feeds -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 777 var -R
chmod 777 media -R
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t .
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add index.php to the url like this:

```
https://website.test/index.php/admin
```