# Unable to access Admin Panel 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, centos

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 on a CentOS VPS.

I'm trying to copy my Magento store from a web hosting server to my backup server(The VPS)

I ensured mod_rewrite was on for apache, the front-end now works properly. But now i'm unable to access the admin. Or i can but under really weird circumstances.

For instance, i'll access the admin panel typing in

`/IP ADDRESS/Website/admin`

and the panel loads up. I try in credentials but then the web url goes to

```
/websiteindex.php/admin/dashboard/index/key`
```

To fix this, i manually add a / between website and index.php. Appearing like /website/index.php. It works for that single page, but if you click on something else, the intialy error will appear.

I looked into the apache Error_log and it just mentions

```
script '/var/www/html/websiteindex.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Things I've tried:

- Ensured Mod_rewrite is working. Works on the front end.
- Applied MYSQL Query search mentioned here [Error 404 - Can't access backend after moving to new server](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41784/error-404-cant-access-backend-after-moving-to-new-server)
- .htaccess has AllowOverride all at `<directory "/var/www/html>`
- Access admin panel by typing `/IP ADDRESS/website/index.php/admin.` Initial error occurs

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is just because you may forget to add a slash ( ‘/’) at the end of base url in system configuration settings.

```
/IP ADDRESS/Website/
```

Please try adding the same and test it again.

Comment: Looks like this was the solution after all. I did applied this to my VPS Server and it worked. The first i applied it, changes didn't take effect even after restarting. I cleared the Magento Cache by removing the /var/cache folder and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

When you transfer magento1.9 website from live server to localhost, make sure in root folder .htaccess file exists. If not than you wont be able to access admin panel.