# Admin panel showing 404 error after data migration

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, 404, data-migration

I have done data migration from Magento 1.9.4.4 to Magento 2.3.2.
I did reindexing and i am not able to access admin panel.
Admin panel is giving 404 error after migration. Frontend works well.
What should i do?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/transferring-magento-website-admin-panel-url-gives-404

Comment: @MohitPatel i have multiple stores here. will that be affected after running sql command?

Comment: on mind No.but Please take to backup before try... and backup your database

Comment: @MohitPatel I checked all the values are same in my db. still issue exsits. any other soln?

Comment: you try remove var/cache and var/view_preprocessed folder???

Comment: yes.........still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108207/discussion-between-nafisa-and-mohit-patel).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:-**

Check this link and run the sql query

**[Transferring Magento website, admin panel URL gives 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/transferring-magento-website-admin-panel-url-gives-404)**

**Solution 2:-**

run all command like:-

```
remove var/cache and var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Solution 3:-**

Go to your database and search the `core_config_data` table and change `admin/url/use_custom value from 1 to 0`.

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Please accept answer if useful  ...